# For which lower bound of integration $a$ does a definite integral of $f(x)$ from $a$ to $x$ equal its antiderivative $F(x)$ with $C=0$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, roots, indefinite-integrals, bounds-of-integration

For an arbitrary antidifferentiable function $f(x)$, my goal is to construct a definite integral of $f(x)$:
$$
\int_a^x f(t) dt
$$

which is equal to *one* of the infinitely-many antiderivatives of $f(x)$, $F(x)+C$. *Specifically,* the one with a constant of integration $C=0$.

I've come up with the following relation between $a$ and $C$ which *I think* implies the existence of such an $a$:
$$
\int f(x) dx = F(x) + C
$$

$$
\int_a^x f(t) dt = F(x) - F(a)
$$

$$
F(x) - F(a) = F(x) + C
$$

$$
F(a) = -C
$$

But, I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: There is no such thing as **the** antiderivative of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

If $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$, then for *every* real number $C$ the function $F(x) + C$ is *also* a valid antiderivative. Then, when you take the definite integral, you will get

$$\begin{eqnarray} \int_a^x f(x) dx & = & (F(x) + C) - (F(a) + C) \\
& = & F(x) - F(a) \\
\implies F(x) & = & F(a) + \int_a^x f(x) dx \end{eqnarray}$$

So what you have found is that your choice of $C$ is equivalent to fixing the value at $F(a)$.

Comment: Thank you ConMan; so, am I right to conclude that deriving $a$ for a given $C$ is more-or-less equivalent to finding the inverse of $F(x)$ evaluated at $C$, $F^-1(C)$?